# Programar un tarea en Laravel-Window 10

Tags: php, laravel, windows, schedule

comunidad.
¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un script en laravel cada determinado tiempo en Windows? He creado un comando que toma la hora y minuto actual y crea un archivo al cual le añade información, quisiera ejecutarlo cada minuto (con fines de ejemplo). He visitado la documentación y veo que se puede conseguir con schedule:run pero me aparece el siguiente error cuando intento correrlo en la terminal y no se crea el archivo en cuestión.

`2024-01-02 15:36:24 Running ["artisan" php artisan create:File] ................................. 429ms FAIL`

`"C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.0.29-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe" "artisan" php artisan create:File > "NUL" 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que conoces windows la forma de hacerlo seria la siguiente:

- Abre el programador de tareas en Windows.
- Crea una nueva tarea y configura la pestaña "Acciones" de la siguiente manera:

Programa o script: Ruta completa de tu archivo artisan (por ejemplo, `"C:\laragon\www\tu_proyecto\artisan"`).

- Agregar argumentos: `schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1`
- Esto ejecutará el comando schedule:run y redirigirá la salida a NUL.
- Configura la frecuencia en la pestaña "Desencadenadores" para que se ejecute cada minuto.
- Guarda y ejecuta la tarea.

**otra forma de hacerlo seria con:** https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling

Primero, asegúrate de que estás utilizando la sintaxis correcta en tu programación de tareas en el archivo `app/Console/Kernel.php`. Debería verse algo así:

```
$schedule->command('create:File')->everyMinute();
```

al ejecutar el comando php artisan schedule:run, podrías encontrarte con problemas en Windows. Para solucionar esto, puedes agregar el siguiente código al método scheduleTimezone en el mismo archivo `Kernel.php`:

```
protected function scheduleTimezone()
{
    return 'America/New_York'; // Ajusta esto a tu zona horaria
}
```

Ahora, respecto al error que estás obteniendo, parece ser un problema con la ejecución del comando. En Windows, el uso de pipes `(>, 2>&1)` puede no funcionar de la misma manera que en sistemas basados en Unix.

Intenta modificar tu comando para que se ejecute directamente sin redirigir la salida a `NUL`. Debería verse así:

```
"C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.0.29-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe" "artisan" create:File
```